# How to create a wrapper/middleware to all actions in controllers to decrypt incoming requests

Tags: encryption, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

The reason for the wrapper is to decrypt all incoming requests from clients, encryption/decryption was done to make Net Core Api not easily available. I don't like the fact that everybody can access my Net Core API and have seen a number of attempts to parse my data.

Therefore, I decided to create only one Controller that receives encrypted GET/POST requests with the name of Controller and Action. The decryption/encryption logic works fine but that problem is that I need to always create a new condition to the root controller to identify passed names of actions and controllers

Could you please advise if it is possible to create a wrapper
1) Catch a request
2) Decrypt its request object
3) Pass the request to the action/controller to which it belongs to

Giving more details:

This is my RootController with one Process action (All interactions with clients are done via this root controller, the rest controllers are available only for admins)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Process([FromBody] RootRequest request)
{
    //Here I am checking what controller and actions was 
    if (request.c.ToLower() == "news" && request.a.ToLower() == "getnews")
    {
        var newsCtrl = new NewsController();
        var decrypted = DecryptRequest(request.r);
        var reqObject = (NewsRequest)decrypted;
        //return this.RedirectToAction<NewsController>(m => m.GetNews());
        return newsCtrl.GetNews(reqObject);
    }
}
```

This is my request object:

```
public class RootRequest {
    // Endpoint
    public string a { get; set; }
    // Contoller
    public string c { get; set; }
    // Request
    public object r { get; set; }
    // Key
    public string k { get; set; }
}
```

I want to avoid creating this kind of checks:

```
if (request.c.ToLower() == "news" && request.a.ToLower() == "getnews")
```

and create an intermediate wrapper that could only decrypt the request and pass the request further

Comment: I can't make sense of any of this. Perhaps others will have better luck, but you might consider adding some clarifying details.

Comment: Added more details, it is clear now?

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to do this - your application is going to be publicly available regardless of whether or not you encrypt incoming client requests (FYI - HTTPS already does this for you, your implementation is never going to be as good as HTTPS).  You are struggling with an *authentication* issue and taking the wrong approach to it.  Instead, implement proper authentication and rest easy knowing that only those who are authenticated can interact with your server.

Comment: Hi Luke, HTTPS only protects from replacing requests from client to server. I want to make my application publicly available but at the same time, make requests not understandable for users. For example, I have an endpoint GetItems that has pagination and hackers can simply change page number to download all data that I have for 2 mins and all work that you have been doing for 2 years is stolen... They even use different IP so I can't block them...

The idea is to encrypt request from GetItems to something like: jJFKajALKSFasjdkflhjkasd using pulic key and decrypt it on server by private key

Comment: I am using RSA + AES for that, it is commonly used technology - the encyption/decryption. The only question I ask if it is possible to:

1) Catch a request
2) Decrypt its request object 
3) Pass the request further?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to protect data from being seen by your users whilst simultaneously using the data on their devices - this is not possible.  I understand what you're asking, but I'm telling you that your efforts are in vain.  Data present on a users device is always accessible to them.  If you have data that you don't want your users to see - **don't send it to them**.

Comment: This [IDOR prevention](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) and this [REST API security](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md) article may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is creating a coding nightmare. This will become massively unmanagable the more it grows. The correct way to handle this is to use some sort of authentication (JWT) that will prevent unauthorised access. You dont want to be obscuring data for valid consumers just to prevent access. Take a look at this for more details on JWT: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api